# How to prevent large inline images from ruining Gmail layout?

Tags: gmail

I receive lots of emails from people with screenshots, sometimes inlined, and they usually don't bother to scale the image. That means that I have to scroll to the right to get to the "Reply button", and looks generally ugly.

Is there a settings, a Chrome plugin, or a Greasemonkey script that will cause Gmail to resize the inline image if it's too large?

Comment: you could start replying using shortcuts.. :)

Comment: Yup. Enable shortcuts in your Settings and when you are inside gmail, pressing "r" will give you the reply window.

Answer (score 7):

I use Stylebot for Chrome with the following css. It catches images and those ugly copy and paste tables people paste in periodically:

```
body.aAU blockquote {
    max-width: 90%;
}

body.aAU blockquote img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: The image class changes unconditionally. Just have `img { max-width: 100% }` always work. It may effects other UI parts, but not big deal.

Answer (score 5):

Pastymage's suggested extension did not work for me, but an [alternative extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-inline-image-fit/johhpdppebdjlbmkiheopoapdkjohfio) worked well for me.

Comment: Above means which one or all of them didn't work for you? What error you get? Adding little more details would be helpful for future reader.

Comment: Answers can also be sorted in a number of different ways, so "above" really has no meaning. Better to link to the answer to which you are referring.

Comment: The "alternate extension" works great. Thanks.

Comment: 10 years, I can't believe that this is still a problem.  That [Gmail Inline Image Fit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-inline-image-fit/johhpdppebdjlbmkiheopoapdkjohfio/related) extension (aka the alternative extension) does the job nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the great shortcut suggestion, you can [disable images from your e-mails](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=145919) (under General Mail Settings) and manually pick one by one specific senders who you trust won't mess your layout.

Also, here's a [general Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/7780) that [someone oddly said](http://cal.freeshell.org/2009/11/resize-gmail-images/) only works on Gmail.

Comment: Links don't work.

Comment: @orschiro i would argue today that this is a good broken link. take a step back and consider degoogling! 

Answer (score 1):

I used Stylish for FireFox from https://userstyles.org/
In the plugin I created a new style and entered the following css-code to limit the width of images:

```
@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {

img {
   max-width: 800px;
   height: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the userstyle I wrote. It works well for me and it doesn't appear to affect any unwanted elements like other scripts I've seen do. This should only change the size of embedded images inside the body of an email.

For userstyles in **Firefox** use this:

```
@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {
  .h7 {
    max-width: none;
  }

  p.MsoNormal > img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

For userstyles in **Chrome** use this:

```
.h7 {
  max-width: none;
}

p.MsoNormal > img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also for **Chrome**, the settings for "Applies to" should be:

- URLs on the domain
- mail.google.com

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox I was successful with [Stylus addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) and the following CSS for `mail.google.com` domain:

```
.h7 .ii.gt img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know next to nothing about CSS.  However, I was successful in fixing the huge in-line image problem in gmail using stylebot in Chrome with this css code:

```
[data-message-id] > div:nth-child(2) img:not([role=button]):not([role=menu]):not([width]) {
max-width: 100%;
width: auto !important;
height: auto !important;
}
```

See the style as shown inside stylebot in the image below...

[image: image showing style inside stylebot]